# Page Layouts - assign different default values to fields

Tags: page-layout

I am working on a project that has 3 different page layouts for an object. All 3 page layouts have 3 fields, a date field, picklist and text field.

This is what I need:

```
Page Layout 1
Date : formula - today() + 3
Picklist: default - urgent
Text Field: 

Page Layout 2
Date: formula - today() + 5
Picklist: default - normal
Text Field:

Page Layout 3
Date: formula - today() + 10
Picklist: default - low
Text Field:
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want different default values depending on the layout being used - is that correct? Which layout is used typically depends on the user's profile and the record type of the object - are you using both of those?

Comment: I want the value to depend on the record type. I have now solved this problem by creating an APEX class to control the values based on record type. I thought that this would have been possible without coding, but so far I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Did you try using Publisher Actions? I'd have thought that would have worked for you without the need for creating a class.